# Firebase Update specific fields?

Tags: json, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

Im updating my firebase database continuously with this code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");


// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("service.json");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL"

});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("games");

var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = 'games/2017-06-27.json';
var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

fs.watchFile(filePath, function() {

var request = require('request');

var usersRef = ref.child('2017-06-27');



request('http://URL/games/2017-06-27.json', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    var asJson = JSON.parse(body)


    usersRef.update(asJson)

   }
})

});
```

So I get a json with real-time sports data scores, game status etc (using another service). I then use node to check changes on the file where the data is stored and write to the firebase database. It works fine, but I don't want to replace the DB. I just want to update the fields that change, because I have other service adding extra data to this child in the database that i want to keep. How can I update only the fields with changes without replacing the all Database and that way keep other extra data that don't come from this request?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `update()` on a location, Firebase loops over the data that you pass in (in your case `asJson`) and for each key performs a `ref.child(key).set(value)`.

```
Object.keys(asJson).forEach((key) => {
  usersRef.child(key).set(asJson[key]);
})
```

So while it merges the top-level properties of `asJson` with the existing data under `usersRef`, it still replaces the data under each key.

If you want to merge on that level too, you'll have to convert the JSON from a tree into a list of paths. Say your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  user1: {
    name: "Speed_John"
  },
  user2: {
    name: "Frank van Puffelen"
  }
}
```

You will have to convert this to:

```
{
  "user1/name": "Speed_John",
  "user2/name": "Frank van Puffelen"
}
```

```js
var JSON = {
  user1: {
    name: "Speed_John"
  },
  user2: {
    name: "Frank van Puffelen",
    id: 209103
  }
};

var updates = {};
function flatten(json, prefix) {
  Object.keys(json).forEach((key) => {
    var path = (prefix||"")+"/"+key;
    if (typeof json[key] === "object") {
      flatten(json[key], path);
    }
    else {
      updates[path] = json[key];
    }
  });
}

flatten(JSON);
console.log(updates);
```

With this code you can then call:

```
usersRef.update(updates);
```

Comment: As the same secenario For me If Phonenumber matches I need to update the field as status as true , But when I update the field it stores at the end of the document  using cloud functions for firestore. can you help me out of these condition